# Accessing to the ForeignKey model attribute

Tags: python, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to access to the attribute of the model through a ForeignKey, like this :

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=64)

class FooImage(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey('Foo', related_name='image')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='goo/{}/'.format(HERE))
```

I want the name attribute of `Foo` where the `HERE` is. I tried many things as :

```
self.model.name
model.name
self.name
```

But it doesn't work.. So, how can I do that ?

Comment: Instead of `foo` can you use the actual models you are having trouble with. Or a close approximation, this is confusing enough without fake models obscuring it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to django documenation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/ . Here you'll come to know in depth about how related fields can be accessed.

Comment: I don't want to access to it outside my class but inside !

Comment: Can you give usage scenario, in which you want to use it ?

Comment: For save the images in a different folder for each object `Foo`. In my application, it's for save aircraft images inside a folder named with it matriculation.